# Angular material dark theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

Why when I set a dark theme does the background itself remain white? Do I need to install css black background myself? Or can fix this somehow?

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you need to add the `mat-app-background` class to your document's `body` element if you're not using a sidenav container, as documented in the [guide for theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming):

> Finally, if your app's content is **not** placed inside of a `mat-sidenav-container` element, you need to add the `mat-app-background` class to your wrapper element (for example the `body`). This ensures that the proper theme background is applied to your page. - [Theming your Angular Material app > Using a prebuilt theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme)

For example:

```html
<body class="mat-app-background">
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
<!-- ... -->
```